# Why aren't my variables getting saved w/ shared_preferences in Flutter?

Tags: flutter

I am creating an app where user's create a unique Home Page. I want to save the Home Page when users close the app, so I used shared_preferences to save variables that make up user's home page. The variables are exercise1 and exercise1 time and below is my code:

```
class _homeState extends State<home> {
  void sete1() async {
    final prefs2 = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    prefs2.setString(exercise1, "");
  }

  void loade1() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    setState(() {
      exercise1 = (prefs.getString(exercise1) ?? '');
    });
  }

  void sete1time() async {
    final prefs3 = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    prefs3.setString(exercise1time, "");
  }

  void loade1time() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs1 = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    setState(() {
      exercise1time = (prefs1.getString(exercise1time) ?? '');
    });
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    sete1();
    loade1();
    sete1time();
    loade1time();
  }
```

Please tell me why above code is not working! I am setting and getting the variables but they are still not saved when app is closed... (Also, I have code after in the class _homeState but I just haven't posted it here)

edit w/ full code:

```
(bunch of imports)

void main() {
  runApp(const MaterialApp(
    title: 'Hey!',
    home: home(),
  ));
}

class home extends StatefulWidget {
  const home({super.key});

  @override
  State<home> createState() => _homeState();
}

class _homeState extends State<home> {
  void loade1() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    setState(() {
      exercise1 = (prefs.getString(exercise1) ?? '');
    });
  }

  void loade1time() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs1 = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    setState(() {
      exercise1time = (prefs1.getString(exercise1time) ?? '');
    });
  }

  settt() {
    sete1();
    sete1time();
    return SizedBox(height: 0);
  }

(sete1 and sete1time are defined in another file as:
sete1() async {
  final prefs2 = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  prefs2.setString(exercise1, exercise1);
  return (SizedBox(height: 0));
}

sete1time() async {
  final prefs3 = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  prefs3.setString(exercise1time, exercise1time);
  return (SizedBox(height: 0));
}
) 

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    loade1();
    loade1time();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        centerTitle: true,
        title: const Text('Hey!'),
      ),
      body: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
        children: <Widget>[
          SizedBox(
            height: 20,
          ),
          const Text(
            'Here:',
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30),
            textAlign: TextAlign.left,
          ),
          if (exercise1 != "") ...[
            one(exercise1),
            SizedBox(
              height: 15,
            ),
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                SizedBox(
                  width: 70,
                  height: 57,
                  child: TextButton(
                    onPressed: null,
                    style: TextButton.styleFrom(
                      backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
                    ),
                    child: Text(
                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                      exercise1time,
                      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                const SizedBox(
                  width: 5,
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  width: 150,
                  height: 65,
                  child: Card(
                    color: Colors.blue,
                    child: Center(
                      child: Text(
                        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                        exercise1,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                IconButton(
                  iconSize: 30.0,
                  icon: const Icon(
                    Icons.info_outline_rounded,
                    color: Colors.blue,
                  ),
                  onPressed: () {
                    Navigator.push(
                      context,
                      MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => e12),
                    );
                  },
                ),
                IconButton(
                  iconSize: 30.0,
                  icon: Icon(
                    Icons.description_rounded,
                    color: Colors.blue,
                  ),
                  onPressed: () {
                    Navigator.push(
                      context,
                      MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => e1),
                    );
                  },
                ),
                IconButton(
                  iconSize: 30.0,
                  icon: Icon(
                    Icons.edit_rounded,
                    color: Colors.blue,
                  ),
                  onPressed: () {
                    Navigator.push(
                      context,
                      MaterialPageRoute(
                          builder: (context) => const edit_exercise1()),
                    );
                  },
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ],
          if (exercise2 != "") ...[
            two(exercise2),
            SizedBox(
              height: 15,
            ),
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                SizedBox(
                  width: 70,
                  height: 57,
                  child: TextButton(
                    onPressed: null,
                    style: TextButton.styleFrom(
                      backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
                    ),
                    child: Text(
                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                      exercise2time,
                      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                const SizedBox(
                  width: 5,
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  width: 150,
                  height: 65,
                  child: Card(
                    color: Colors.blue,
                    child: Center(
                      child: Text(
                        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                        exercise2,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                IconButton(
                  iconSize: 30.0,
                  icon: const Icon(
                    Icons.info_outline_rounded,
                    color: Colors.blue,
                  ),
                  onPressed: () {
                    Navigator.push(
                      context,
                      MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => e22),
                    );
                  },
                ),
                IconButton(
                  iconSize: 30.0,
                  icon: Icon(
                    Icons.description_rounded,
                    color: Colors.blue,
                  ),
                  onPressed: () {
                    Navigator.push(
                      context,
                      MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => e2),
                    );
                  },
                ),
                IconButton(
                  iconSize: 30.0,
                  icon: Icon(
                    Icons.edit_rounded,
                    color: Colors.blue,
                  ),
                  onPressed: () {
                    Navigator.push(
                      context,
                      MaterialPageRoute(
                          builder: (context) => const edit_exercise2()),
                    );
                  },
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ],
          if (exercise3 != "") ...[
            three(exercise3),
            SizedBox(
              height: 15,
            ),
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                SizedBox(
                  width: 70,
                  height: 57,
                  child: TextButton(
                    onPressed: null,
                    style: TextButton.styleFrom(
                      backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
                    ),
                    child: Text(
                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                      exercise3time,
                      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                const SizedBox(
                  width: 5,
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  width: 150,
                  height: 65,
                  child: Card(
                    color: Colors.blue,
                    child: Center(
                      child: Text(
                        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                        exercise3,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                IconButton(
                  iconSize: 30.0,
                  icon: const Icon(
                    Icons.info_outline_rounded,
                    color: Colors.blue,
                  ),
                  onPressed: () {
                    Navigator.push(
                      context,
                      MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => e32),
                    );
                  },
                ),
                IconButton(
                  iconSize: 30.0,
                  icon: Icon(
                    Icons.description_rounded,
                    color: Colors.blue,
                  ),
                  onPressed: () {
                    Navigator.push(
                      context,
                      MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => e3),
                    );
                  },
                ),
                IconButton(
                  iconSize: 30.0,
                  icon: Icon(
                    Icons.edit_rounded,
                    color: Colors.blue,
                  ),
                  onPressed: () {
                    Navigator.push(
                      context,
                      MaterialPageRoute(
                          builder: (context) => const edit_exercise3()),
                    );
                  },
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ],
          if (exercise4 != "") ...[
            four(exercise4),
            SizedBox(
              height: 15,
            ),
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                SizedBox(
                  width: 70,
                  height: 57,
                  child: TextButton(
                    onPressed: null,
                    style: TextButton.styleFrom(
                      backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
                    ),
                    child: Text(
                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                      exercise4time,
                      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                const SizedBox(
                  width: 5,
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  width: 150,
                  height: 65,
                  child: Card(
                    color: Colors.blue,
                    child: Center(
                      child: Text(
                        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                        exercise4,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                IconButton(
                  iconSize: 30.0,
                  icon: const Icon(
                    Icons.info_outline_rounded,
                    color: Colors.blue,
                  ),
                  onPressed: () {
                    Navigator.push(
                      context,
                      MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => e42),
                    );
                  },
                ),
                IconButton(
                  iconSize: 30.0,
                  icon: Icon(
                    Icons.description_rounded,
                    color: Colors.blue,
                  ),
                  onPressed: () {
                    Navigator.push(
                      context,
                      MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => e4),
                    );
                  },
                ),
                IconButton(
                  iconSize: 30.0,
                  icon: Icon(
                    Icons.edit_rounded,
                    color: Colors.blue,
                  ),
                  onPressed: () {
                    Navigator.push(
                      context,
                      MaterialPageRoute(
                          builder: (context) => const edit_exercise4()),
                    );
                  },
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ],
          if (exercise5 != "") ...[
            five(exercise5),
            SizedBox(
              height: 15,
            ),
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                SizedBox(
                  width: 70,
                  height: 57,
                  child: TextButton(
                    onPressed: null,
                    style: TextButton.styleFrom(
                      backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
                    ),
                    child: Text(
                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                      exercise5time,
                      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                const SizedBox(
                  width: 5,
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  width: 150,
                  height: 65,
                  child: Card(
                    color: Colors.blue,
                    child: Center(
                      child: Text(
                        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                        exercise5,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                IconButton(
                  iconSize: 30.0,
                  icon: const Icon(
                    Icons.info_outline_rounded,
                    color: Colors.blue,
                  ),
                  onPressed: () {
                    Navigator.push(
                      context,
                      MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => e52),
                    );
                  },
                ),
                IconButton(
                  iconSize: 30.0,
                  icon: Icon(
                    Icons.description_rounded,
                    color: Colors.blue,
                  ),
                  onPressed: () {
                    Navigator.push(
                      context,
                      MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => e5),
                    );
                  },
                ),
                IconButton(
                  iconSize: 30.0,
                  icon: Icon(
                    Icons.edit_rounded,
                    color: Colors.blue,
                  ),
                  onPressed: () {
                    Navigator.push(
                      context,
                      MaterialPageRoute(
                          builder: (context) => const edit_exercise5()),
                    );
                  },
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ],
          if (exercise6 != "") ...[
            six(exercise6),
            SizedBox(
              height: 15,
            ),
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                SizedBox(
                  width: 70,
                  height: 57,
                  child: TextButton(
                    onPressed: null,
                    style: TextButton.styleFrom(
                      backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
                    ),
                    child: Text(
                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                      exercise6time,
                      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                const SizedBox(
                  width: 5,
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  width: 150,
                  height: 65,
                  child: Card(
                    color: Colors.blue,
                    child: Center(
                      child: Text(
                        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                        exercise6,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                IconButton(
                  iconSize: 30.0,
                  icon: const Icon(
                    Icons.info_outline_rounded,
                    color: Colors.blue,
                  ),
                  onPressed: () {
                    Navigator.push(
                      context,
                      MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => e62),
                    );
                  },
                ),
                IconButton(
                  iconSize: 30.0,
                  icon: Icon(
                    Icons.description_rounded,
                    color: Colors.blue,
                  ),
                  onPressed: () {
                    Navigator.push(
                      context,
                      MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => e6),
                    );
                  },
                ),
                IconButton(
                  iconSize: 30.0,
                  icon: Icon(
                    Icons.edit_rounded,
                    color: Colors.blue,
                  ),
                  onPressed: () {
                    Navigator.push(
                      context,
                      MaterialPageRoute(
                          builder: (context) => const edit_exercise6()),
                    );
                  },
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ],
          if (exercise7 != "") ...[
            seven(exercise7),
            SizedBox(
              height: 15,
            ),
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                SizedBox(
                  width: 70,
                  height: 57,
                  child: TextButton(
                    onPressed: null,
                    style: TextButton.styleFrom(
                      backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
                    ),
                    child: Text(
                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                      exercise7time,
                      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                const SizedBox(
                  width: 5,
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  width: 150,
                  height: 65,
                  child: Card(
                    color: Colors.blue,
                    child: Center(
                      child: Text(
                        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                        exercise7,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                IconButton(
                  iconSize: 30.0,
                  icon: const Icon(
                    Icons.info_outline_rounded,
                    color: Colors.blue,
                  ),
                  onPressed: () {
                    Navigator.push(
                      context,
                      MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => e72),
                    );
                  },
                ),
                IconButton(
                  iconSize: 30.0,
                  icon: Icon(
                    Icons.description_rounded,
                    color: Colors.blue,
                  ),
                  onPressed: () {
                    Navigator.push(
                      context,
                      MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => e7),
                    );
                  },
                ),
                IconButton(
                  iconSize: 30.0,
                  icon: Icon(
                    Icons.edit_rounded,
                    color: Colors.blue,
                  ),
                  onPressed: () {
                    Navigator.push(
                      context,
                      MaterialPageRoute(
                          builder: (context) => const edit_exercise7()),
                    );
                  },
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ],
          SizedBox(
            height: 50,
            width: 150,
            child: OutlinedButton(
              style: OutlinedButton.styleFrom(
                side: BorderSide(color: Colors.blue, width: 1),
              ),
              child: Text('Add Exercise'),
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.push(
                  context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const add_exercise()),
                );
              },
            ),
          ),
          SizedBox(
            height: 20,
          ),
          settt(),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Please note that all functions like one() are defined. Ultimately, users are creating their own schedule, which I want to be saved. Thank you for your helps!

Answer (score 0):

The `initState()` is the first piece of code that is executing.

and the first thing you are doing is you are **overwriting** old values with this new default value in `sete1()` and in `sete1time()`.

**Solution:**
remove the call to `sete1()` and `sete1time()` from `initState()`.
It should become like this:

```
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    //sete1();  *** remove this line
    loade1();
    //sete1time();*** and remove this line
    loade1time();
  }
```

Comment: I just tried this, but when I close the app, home page is still not saved so e1 and e1time variables didn't save either....

Comment: You need to call  sete1() and sete1time() at the moment you want to save... you did not show your code here but when you are ready to save, just call those two methods, otherwise it wont save

Comment: Do I not have to calls them in initState?

Comment: no, don't call the "set" in initState( ), only call the "load" there.... You, call the "set" later when you want to save... try it...

Comment: and your 2 "set" methods are saving an empty String ""... So, you need to adjust those to save your real values

Comment: It's still not working... can I share my entire code with you by editing my original question pls?

Comment: I want set method to set exercise1 value to current exercise 1 value so I made it prefs2.setString(exercise1, exercise1); and I did same to time

Comment: yes please, edit your question by adding your code

Comment: Were you able to figure it out?

Comment: any updates? Did you find what was wrong?

Comment: sorry... nothing on my side

Comment: Okay could you just explain to be when I call setString I am confused about that part